# How do i get the next day datetime in isoformate

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using the Google Calendar API.
I've read the quickstart

```
>     eventsResult = service.events().list(
             calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
             orderBy='startTime').execute()
```

But I tried to add a timeMax parameter to filter the event i got.
I wish to get the event from now to the end of today.
I start at:

```
> import datetime
 now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

then I got:

```
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'
```

I read that most coder is confused by the datetime.datetime.

Comment: Have you named your file/a file in the current directory `datetime` - what does `datetime.__file__` show you? If it's not something like: `'/usr/lib/python3.5/datetime.py'` which looks like the actual Python library path - that's why

Comment: G:\python\datetime.py<br>
@Jon oh thanks i got the point orz

Comment: yeah... that's not the system one - looks like that's your current file or one in the directory you're using...

Comment: if it's `datetime` could this work? `(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).isoformat()`

Comment: @erasmortg  but if the py run at 2017/8/9 06:29 I hope the result be 2017/8/9/11:59

Comment: @ToMmtDong 11:59 or 23:59?

Comment: oh sorry 23:59
i found .replace(hour=23, minute=59) thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use the module `time` instead. With the function `localtime` with no argument passed you can generate a timestamp with the accuracy of a second.

**Example**

```
>>> import time
>>> ts = time.localtime()
>>> print ts
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=12, tm_min=39, tm_sec=50, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=221, tm_isdst=0)
>>> print ts.tm_year, ts.tm_mon, ts.tm_mday
2017 8 9
>>> print ts[3:6]
(12, 39, 50)
```

As you see, you have several methods to extract the information from the timestamp.

---

**[EDIT]**

If the ISO-Format of the timestamp is important, ignore my answer... ;)

Comment: Yep I need ISO-Format . ^。^

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> from datetime import date,timedelta
>>> dt.datetime.today() - timedelta(days=-1)
#datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 10, 18, 16, 29, 785131)
>>> Td = dt.datetime.today() - timedelta(days=-1)
>>> Td
#datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 10, 18, 16, 41, 786500)
>>> Td = Td.isoformat()
>>> Td
#'2017-08-10T18:16:41.786500'
```

> > >

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem with datetime.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
night = now.replace(hour=23, minute=59)

#I'm at UTC+8
utcNow = now-datetime.timedelta(hours=8)
utcnight = night - datetime.timedelta(hours=8)

print (utcNow.isoformat() + 'Z')
print(utcnight.isoformat() + 'Z')
```

> 2017-08-10T02:48:16.413384Z
>   2017-08-10T15:59:16.413384Z

for my local time it is:
2017-08-10 10:48:16.413384Z
2017-08-10 23:59:16.413384Z